# How can we determine how much web requests per second a machine can handle without load testing?

Tags: performance, web-services, servlets, load-balancing, scalability

What are some of the things that determine how many web requests a single machine can handle? In general what's an average number (requests per second) that most machines should be able to handle? For example, I see some answers that say 2k requests/s can easily be handled. How about 5k? 10k? etc.

I'm basically trying to do my best at estimating how many machines I'd need to scale to some high throughput, before I dive into load testing.

Comment: only you can answer this question after load testing your environment - it's going to depend on the server specs but also what the server is doing, interconnects, etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That is possible through **performance modelling** but the answers will have 5-10% error margin.
If you know exact size of web request then probably you can find your nw limit and thus this gives you maximum possible request acceptance limit. some exploratory test with sample test you can get the cpu time required by each request roughly(in terms of response time or thoughput). thus you can extrapolate the results for higher number of requests using many theorems examples, **little's law**. Using this theorem you can find maximum no of users (request here) can be supported on a give hw for a give acceptable response time.

but this all is done after tuning your application to expected level otherwise you will end up with lot of hw because of lack of tuning.

Comment: correct strategy is called sizing in such situations.